# PulseEffects pavucontrol issue

Tags: pulseaudio

I use UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS.

I discovered an issue with PulseEffects audio processor.

When we use it and because any reason the audio is cut, when audio is restored, pulse audio control (pavucontrol) set any recording device to the PulseEffects microphone input, regardless if it was being used or not.

We have to change it manually.

It gives a silent audio into the used recording device up we set the correct pavucontrol parameter.

How to avoid it to get a permanent pavucontrol PulseEffects apps input only?